# Concatenating and mixing multiple video and audio files

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I am currently working on a utility that is responsible for pulling audio and video files from the cloud and merging them together via FFMPEG. As I am new to FFMPEG, I have a certain issue when it comes to combining video concatenation with both video and audio delay.

Currently, I have a working FFMPEG arg if there is only 1 video file present and it needs to be merged with multiple files.

`ffmpeg -i input1.mkv -i input1.mka -i input2.mka -i input3.mka -i input4.mka -filter_complex "[1:a]adelay=0s:all=1[a1pad];[2:a]adelay=20s:all=1[a2pad];[3:a]adelay=30s:all=1[a3pad];[4:a]adelay=40s:all=1[a4pad];[a1pad][a2pad][a3pad][a4pad]amix=inputs=4:weights=1|1|1|1[aout]" -map [aout] -map 0:0 output4.mkv`

The delays you see in there are determined by subtracting the start time of each file from the start time of the earliest created audio or video file. I know that if I wanted to create a horizontal stack of multiple videos, I could just do:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mkv -i input1.mka -i input2.mkv -i input2.mka -i input3.mka -i input4.mka
-filter_complex 
"[2:v]tpad=start_duration=120:color=black[vpad]; 
 [3:a]adelay=120000:all=1[a2pad]; 
 [4:a]adelay=180000:all=1[a3pad];
 [5:a]adelay=200000:all=1[a4pad]; 
 [0:v][vpad]hstack=inputs=2[vout]; 
 [1:a][a2pad][a3pad][a4pad]amix=inputs=4:weights=1|1|1|1[aout]" 
 -map [vout] -map [aout] 
 output.mkv
```

but what I want to do is both keep those delays for the audio and video files AND concatenate (not stack) those videos, how would I go about doing that?